# Will Datastore fetch Reference'd Entity if already fetched?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
class Author (db.Model)
   name = db.StringProperty()

class Book (db.Model)
   author = db.ReferenceProperty (collection_name="books", indexed=True)
   name = db.StringProperty()

author = Author.get (author_key)
q = Book.all()
q.filter ("author =", author.key())
q.filter ("name =", "BOOK_NAME")
book = q.fetch(1)[0]

book.author.name
```

Will the last statement (`book.author.name`) result in a another read on datastore?

Answer (score 2):

Yes

If you are just starting out consider using ndb, which has cacheing of get requests built in.

Comment: Still one extra query will be considered even if it is served from ndb cache.

Comment: Yes that's correct with this sort of access pattern.  ndb only caches get's not queries.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily suggesting ndb would solve the specific problem but it does introduce some efficiencies with it's built in caching.

Comment: took your advice(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588836/model-design-pattern-for-google-app-engine#comment24571184_15588836) last time and moved on to ndb.Lots of performance improvement compared to db.